# How to insert thousands of JSON Array Dumps in Mongodb quickly?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have around 20,000 files with JSON array in them. I would like to DUMP all these files into MongoDB hosted locally. I am using mongoimport for this purpose.

Is there any way I can speed up the process ?

These 20,000 files contains around 12 million records.

Comment: What do you define as "quickly"? There is no real quick way to insert 12 million records.

Comment: if you have 20,000 json files and 12 million records it sounds like you can't just go json->mongo.. should use something like JAVA or another language that you can do an insert with. It's not going to be a 1-2min job though..

Answer (score 0):

My Mongo version is 2.6.12 in a linux server with 32 cores. I have imported 134 millions of records into MongoDB. The amount of input files is around 1700 and the format is JSON array. My testing results are as follows:

1. mongoimport: 100K records a time. Import 100K records in 4min 50s.(Before Mongo version 3.0.0, there is no "--numInsertionWorkers" parameters, so I conduct single-threaded import. You can try with that parameter if newer version is available.)
2. mongoimport: 50K records a time. Import 100K records in 2min 20s.
3. [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) (single-threaded): a records a time, use [insert](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) method. Import 100K records in 30s.
4. PyMongo (multi-threaded, thread number is 8): a record a time. Import 134 millions of records in 1hour 32min. It's nearly linear speedup.

The reason possibly falls in: A file with 100K records is a large chunk which is time-consuming for "mongoimport" to handle. I haven't figured out why PyMongo is faster than mongoimport. Are JSON files processed faster? So, you could probably try with PyMongo in a multi-threaded way.